# r Calculating Cronbach Alpha and representing it with Knit

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am calculating Cronbach's Alpha for two tables using this method:

```
AlphaA <- cronbach.alpha(DadosA[,-1:-5])
AlphaB <- cronbach.alpha(DadosB[,-1:-5])
```

Yes, I am removing the first five columns from my data before calculating.
This is working nice and when calling them in console I am getting:

```
>AlphaA
Cronbach's alpha for the 'DadosA[, -1:-5]' data-set

Items: 53
Sample units: 62
alpha: 0.897

>AlphaB
Cronbach's alpha for the 'DadosB[, -1:-5]' data-set

Items: 53
Sample units: 71
alpha: 0.871
```

Which is the expected result!
My doubt is how to insert only the alpha value in Knit, not all data. I have tried doing this:

```
`r AlphaA`
`r AlphaB`
```

But I get the following result:

```
0.8971043, 62, 53, FALSE, DadosA[, -1:-5] 
0.8708021, 71, 53, FALSE, DadosB[, -1:-5]
```

Any clues on what should I change in order to get only the alpha value? I mean, only 0.8971043 when I call AlphaA and only 0.8708021 when I call AlphaB.

Comment: What are the class and the structure of "AlphaA"? As your example is not reproducible, we cannot run it ourselves.

Comment: Found answer! As the value is the first element, all I needed was to use `r AlphaA[1]` and `r AlphaB[1]`. Thanks for trying to help me Pascal.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer!

As the value is the first element, all I needed was to use this:

```
`r AlphaA[1]` 
`r AlphaB[1]`
```